# Adding new field to existing database table in django python

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, database-migration

I have a Postgresql database connected with my django application, Now I have a existing table in the database and want to add a new field to this table using the migrate command. But when I try to add this new field to my models.py and run makemigration and migrate commands, django says there are no new migrations to apply. Can you help me with how to add a new field to existing table.

Comment: Editing the models then running `makemigrations` is the correct way to add the field. So if that doesn't work, you'll need to add more information to your question to explain what the problem is. What is the model? Does it have `managed=False`? What migrations already exist for the app?

Comment: Have you added your app to the `INSTALLED_APPS` setting?

Comment: Yes I did add into installed apps and tried with that particular app name, not sure why it isn't detecting

Answer (score 0):

Try running makemigrations command specifying your app name like this:

```
 python manage.py makemigrations myapp
```

and then try running migrate command

Comment: Try removing the **migrations** folder inside your app folder and run the **makemigrations** and **migrate** command

Comment: Happening the same here, I tried everything known, makemigrations and migrate, removing migrations directory from the app, ensuring that the app is on installed apps. Worth to mention that I'm using django 1.11.4

Answer (score 0):

After a long research I got a solution as below:

```
pip install django-extensions
```

and add this in the install app of settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django_extensions'
]
```

Now, run migrations for your installed apps

```
python manage.py makemigrations your_app_name
python manage.py migrtate your_app_name
```

Done! See Your Database...